# MATLAB plot image margin removal and aspect ratio keeping

Tags: image, matlab, plot, video-capture

I have following code which basically trying to create a video based on a series images of size 256 X 256 X 3, where 3 is the RGB channls:

```
close all
clc

%% creating image volum
img = phantom(256);
img = repmat(img, [1,1,3]);

figure(1)
vidfile = VideoWriter('testVideo.mp4','MPEG-4');
open(vidfile);

%% loop to ceate images with different colors
for n = 1:120
    a = n/120;
    img(:,:,1) = img(:,:,2)*a;
    img(:,:,3) = img(:,:,2)*(1-a);
    imagesc(img), axis off
    set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1])
    drawnow
    videoFrame(n) = getframe(gcf); 
    writeVideo(vidfile,videoFrame(n));
end

close(vidfile)
```

However, although I got rid of the margin, I cannot get the image aspect ratio right. The image looks like this:

[image]

The goal is to remove the margin of the plot and maintain the aspect ratio of the images. In this case, it should be a square image with size 256 X 256 that looks like this:

[image]

Any pointers? Some sample code would be very nice. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation of `VideoWritter` says that you can give it `Height` and `Width` values. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.
The phantom *dataset* is square, but the phantom *image* does not occupy the whole dataset; instead, there is a margin on the left and right sides that is greater than on the top and bottom sides.
Simply add one line of [truesize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/truesize.html) to the data to plot it as-is will maintain the aspect ratio.

```
...
imagesc(img), axis off
set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1])
truesize(gcf,[256,256]) % <<<< Just add this
drawnow
...
```

[image]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

However, you need to do an additional step if you want a circular phantom without a margin.

```
img = phantom(256);
img = repmat(img(12:245,41:216), [1,1,3]); % <<<< I changed this line

figure(1)
vidfile = VideoWriter('testVideo.mp4','MPEG-4');
open(vidfile);

%% loop to ceate images with different colors
for n = 1:120
    a = n/120;
    img(:,:,1) = img(:,:,2)*a;
    img(:,:,3) = img(:,:,2)*(1-a);
    imagesc(img), axis off
    set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1])
    truesize(gcf,[256,256]) % <<<< I changed this line
    drawnow
    videoFrame(n) = getframe(gcf); 
    writeVideo(vidfile,videoFrame(n));
end

close(vidfile)
```

[image]

That's a chubby phantom.